# How to split a string column into two columns with a 'variable' delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, strsplit

I have a rough df extracted from a PDF data table that is composed of a single column containing strings. Each entry in the column is in the following form:

```
Mayor ............... Paul Jones
Senator ................. Billy Twister
Congress Rep. .......... Chris Rock
Chief of Staff ....... Tony Allen
```

I would like to use `string.split(pat=".")` to split these strings into two columns for `Title` and `Name` using the period strings. However, each entry in the column has different lengths for the period string delimiter. As expected, if I use `pat="."` or `pat="......."`, for instance, I end up with inconsistent splits.

My goal is to implement a way for the delimiter to be able to handle a range of period string lengths for a given minimum and maximum length. I have googled around with this question and have not been able to find a direct answer. Is this possible to implement?

Comment: If you're using regex, `\.+` will match one or more periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with the regex `\s+\.+\s+`, which splits by 1+ spaces, 1+ periods, 1+ spaces:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Mayor ............... Paul Jones', 'Senator ................. Billy Twister', 'Congress Rep. .......... Chris Rock', 'Chief of Staff ....... Tony Allen']})

df[['Title', 'Name']] = df['A'].str.split('\s+\.+\s+', expand=True)

#                                          A           Title           Name
# 0         Mayor ............... Paul Jones           Mayor     Paul Jones
# 1  Senator ................. Billy Twister         Senator  Billy Twister
# 2      Congress Rep. .......... Chris Rock   Congress Rep.     Chris Rock
# 3        Chief of Staff ....... Tony Allen  Chief of Staff     Tony Allen
```